# Pass data through semantic react ui card component in the onclick() method

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to get data passed in the onclick method on the Semantic React UI card component, with the simple objective of drilling into a detail page on a record displayed in the card component.

I understand that this component creates a react synthetic event for the onclick() method and passes in (event, data) to the defined function.

How can I see what is actually being passed in though? I try to log out JSON.stringify(data) in the onHandleClick() function i've defined to see what's there, but i get a 'converting circular structure to JSON' error.

All I am looking to do is pass through the key value on the card to the detail component and then I can filter out my redux store to get the single record and display it in the detail component.

The component is below:
Card.js

```
  newsArticles() {
    if (this.props.content.isLoading) {
      return (
        <Grid.Column stretched>
          <Message>
            <Message.Header>Not Quite There Yet</Message.Header>
            <p>To see your content, please select a channel from the dropdown list above</p>
          </Message>
        </Grid.Column>
      );
    } else {
      const cards = this.props.content.data.map( article => {
        let contentId = article.key;
        return (
          <Grid.Column stretched>
            <Card key={contentId} onClick={ ( event, data) => this.handleOnClick(event, data)} style={{ marginBottom: '2em'}}>
              <Image src={this.props.auth.data.sfInstanceUrl + article.image} />
              <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>
                  {article.title}
                </Card.Header>
                <Card.Description>
                  {article.excerpt}
                </Card.Description>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </Grid.Column>
        );
      });
      return cards;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Segment placeholder>
        <Grid centered stackable columns="4" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="top">
          <Grid.Row style={{ marginBottom: '2em' }}>
              {this.newsArticles()}
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
      </Segment>
    )
  };
```

To handle the click event, i'm just trying to log out what's delivered through the onclick() method. Ultimately, i'd just like to pass out the contentId variable to the handle function..

```
  handleOnClick( event, data ) {
    // function to navigate to single article
    console.log(`data is: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data contains `props`, which contains its `children` (array of components). each `child` is a component and contains a property `_owner` that references itself, hence the circular reference error.

since I believe you are interested in other props than its `children` you can do as the following:

```
  handleOnClick( event, {children, ...data} ) {
    // function to navigate to single article
    console.log(`data is: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  }
```